# How to store more than 10 digit number in javascript using the var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First of all,

What am i doing ?
   I have to set the limit of emails in our product in webpage.It's handled with the javascript for validation.It handles upto 8 digit numbers fine. But in our QA team enters the more than 17 digit number in the text box of other email field.It throw the negative message.What can i do ???

## My sample code is:

```
if(form.otherEmails) {
            if(validEmailArray.endsWith(',')){
                 var otherEmailLength = validEmailArray.substring(0,validEmailArray.length-1).split(",");
                 var setLimitOtherEmail = window.parent.document.getElementById('setLimitOtherEmail').value;

                if(setLimitOtherEmail == '-1'){
                   form.otherEmails.value = otherEmailLength;
                }
                else if(otherEmailLength.length <= setLimitOtherEmail){
                   form.otherEmails.value = otherEmailLength;
                }
                else{
                    alert("More than "+setLimitOtherEmail+ " " +"Recipient emailIds not allowed in this section.\nIf you want to send it to more recipients, Please create a Bulk Contact Group.");
                    form.otherEmails.focus();
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
                form.otherEmails.value = validEmailArray;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing each of the numbers into Integers before performing any comparison operations on them.

`var setLimitOtherEmail = parseInt(window.parent.document.getElementById('setLimitOtherEmail').value);`

Other than that are you certain otherEmailLength is actually the number that you want? From the looks of it you are taking the substring of validEmail array and splitting it on "," but it doesn't look like you actually get the length of the array. Try adding .length to the end of the value of otherEmailLength.

```
var otherEmailLength = validEmailArray.substring(0,validEmailArray.length-1).split(",").length;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the limit being a string, and when a string is being compared to a number (length) the number is coerced into a string, not the other way around.

These are then compared lexicographically - and lexicographically "9" is more (>) than "19".

You need to use `parseInt(setLimitOtherEmail, 10)` to get the value as a number before comparing them.